Google Drive Upload API: We're sorry but your computer or network may be sending automated queries
I recently developed an Next.js web app (deployed using Vercel) in which the user may share their screen, and a snapshot of their screen recording will be uploaded to a GDrive folder every 10 seconds.
Now with consistent user traffic (around 10-20 accessing the web app at the same time), the GDrive Upload API keeps on returning: sorry but your computer or network may be sending automated queries most of the time.
For context, the backend API which uploads these slices of recordings are also a Next.js web app with the following code excerpt:
import { google } from 'googleapis';

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
const FOLDER_ID = GDRIVE_FOLDER_ID;

const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
  GDRIVE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
  undefined,
  GDRIVE_PRIVATE_KEY?.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
  SCOPES
);

const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth, retry:true });

async function uploadFile(fileName: string, filePath: string, mimeType: string, parentFolderId: string) {
  try {
    console.log(`Starting upload for file: ${fileName}`);
    console.log(`File path: ${filePath}`);
    console.log(`MIME type: ${mimeType}`);
    console.log(`Parent folder ID: ${parentFolderId}`);

     // Get the file size
    const stats = fs.statSync(filePath);
    const fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;

    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    let uploadedBytes = 0;
    fileStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
      uploadedBytes += chunk.length;
      const progress = (uploadedBytes / fileSizeInBytes) * 100;
      console.log(`Upload progress: ${progress.toFixed(2)}%`);
    });

    fileStream.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error(`Error reading file: ${error}`);
    });

    console.log("Final parent folder ID", [parentFolderId]);
    
    const response = await drive.files.create({
      requestBody: {
        name: fileName,
        parents: [parentFolderId],
        mimeType: mimeType,
      },
      media: {
        mimeType,
        body: fileStream,
      },
      fields: 'id,parents,size',
      supportsAllDrives: true,
      uploadType: "media"
    });

    console.log(`Upload completed. File ID: ${response.data.id}`);
    console.log(`File parents: ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}, parents: ${JSON.stringify(response.data.parents)}`);
    console.log(`File size: ${response.data.size} bytes`);

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to upload file: ${error.message}`);
    if (error.response) {
      console.error(`Error response: ${JSON.stringify(error.response.data)}`);
    }
    throw new Error(`Failed to upload file: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

I've read through some other similar SO issues from 2020, it seems the issue is due to access tokens being required, but I'm sure that is not the issue as the googleapis package used already handles that and uploading screen recording videos locally from my computer works fine (as in localhost). I am also sure that it is not a rate limiting problem, as the RPS to the API is very, very small compared to the limits imposed by Google.
Any ideas/clues on how we can resolve this issue?
